# appending options in select tag not working

Tags: jquery

```
success: function(response){
    var object = $.parseJSON(response);
    var options = '';
    $.each(object,function(id,roomno){
        options += '<options value="'+id+'">'+roomno+'</option>';
    });
    $("#rooms").append(options);
}
```

I have checked in my console the html tag is fine but why its not appending options to select tag `#rooms`. Please note that this is within `$(document).ready()`.

Thanks.

Comment: it should be option not options, and roomno is object, you may use roomno.something

Comment: @ridvanzoro about roomo.something you are not completely right on JSON, check out the docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: "am i not completely right ", let me say if i have json returned like `[{"Id":1,"Cid":1,"Path":"132"},{"Id":2,"Cid":1,"Path":"133"}]`,how can i get path? I will do `options += '<options value="'+id+'">'+roomno.path+'</option>';` Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your opening tag is not correct, `options` must be `option`.

Try change this

```
options += '<options value="'+id+'">'+roomno+'</option>';
```

into this:

```
options += '<option value="'+id+'">'+roomno+'</option>';
```

Comment: hahah oh damn :) Thank you so much thats a silly question